# How to replace 4 kilometer fiber optic cabling for ethernet with wireless?

Tags: wlan

My use case is for security camera installations. I need to interconnect several remote locations into a central monitoring station. Right now, I'm using pools of copper wired connections, all linked together using fiber optic cables. But I need to replace this fiber optic cabling with wireless. What at the devices that I should be using? What are the popular vendors for these?

Comment: I'd stick with the cabling if possible.

Comment: @Ignacio, not always possible.  But if it's already in place I think that might make sense.

Comment: Security via long range wireless? You are aware of just how easily that can be interfered with, aren't you? e.g. A few cm of metal foil over one of the antennas will completely kill the link.

Comment: So would a bit of foil over the lens.

Comment: laser would do the job if you have line of sight

Answer (score 2):

I have been using this, http://www.ubnt.com/bullet along with good antennas for my wireless links. I prefer using the Bullet + antenna because it gives me far more choices in antennas then a having the radio and antenna built into one unit.  I have a 13KM link going with two Bullets and 24dBi antennas.

What exactly you need will depend on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ubiquity are very good. The bullet's are very stable.  You'll also need an access point either from ubiquty or from Mikrotik with a suitable omni antenna. 4km is considered close.  I had to do exactly what you're doing once before but used trango at the time.